# Using a form token when user isn't logged in

Tags: authentication, session, forms, post, token

I noticed that a lot of sites send a random token with form posts even though the user is not logged into a service requiring authentication. I understand the use of a token when you have an authenticated session, but what is the point in sending one when they aren't authenticated?

Is it common practice to create a session when a user isn't logged in and pair a token to it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is common to track where visitors go, storing search results, or shopping cart information.  Sessions can be used for a lot more than just authentication.